# Gatling - Long Polling in a loop - asynchronous response - loop doesn't work as intended

Tags: scala, automated-tests, performance-testing, gatling

This is my first question ever on this website, please bear with me patiently.

I'm trying to make an http long polling program for a project using Gatling. While crawling through many questions on stackoverflow, though I've been able to reunite separate concepts into a piece of syntactically correct code, sadly, it doesn't do what is intended to do.

When a status code of 200 is obtained after any request, the loop should break and the test would be considered as approved. If the status code is different to 200, it should keep the connection alive and polling, not failing the test.

When the .tryMax value is reached and all responses gave a status different to 200, the loop should break and the test should be considered as failed.

Using the difference operator (!=) doesn't work either, so then I took the decision to alternatively use .equals() and test the loop, to no avail.

Being new to both Gatling and Scala, I'm still trying to figure out what's wrong with this code, execution-wise:

```
    def HttpPollingAsync() = {
     asLongAs(session => session("statuss").validate[String].equals("200")) {
      exec(
        polling
         .every(10 seconds)
         .exec(
         http("polling-async-response")
         .post("/" + BaseURL + "/resource-async-response")
         .headers(headers)
         .body(RawFileBody("requestdata.json"))
         .check(
            status.is(200),
            jsonPath("$.status").is("200"),
            jsonPath("$.status").saveAs("statuss")
            ))
        ).exec(polling.stop)
    }
}

val scn = scenario("asyncpolling")
        .tryMax(60){
            exec(HttpPollingAsync())
             }

setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(10))).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

The exception I get when running this piece of code is (it's just syntactically correct):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: There were no requests sent during the simulation, reports won't be generated
    at io.gatling.charts.report.ReportsGenerator.generateFor(ReportsGenerator.scala:49)
    at io.gatling.app.RunResultProcessor.generateReports(RunResultProcessor.scala:59)
    at io.gatling.app.RunResultProcessor.processRunResult(RunResultProcessor.scala:38)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:81)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:46)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:38)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
```

So there's some part when it's never accessed or used.

Any bit of help or pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

an `asLongAs` loop condition is evaluated at the start of the loop - so on your first execution the condition will fail due to there being no session value for `statuss`.

the `doWhile` loop provides checking at the end of the loop.